# How to divide floating point numbers using variables with integer result?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, centos, bc

```
answer=$(echo $(( length / 1024 )) | bc -l)
```

so length is a variable which has a value like `2402267538.` and it needs to be divided by `1024`.

executing this throws this error

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Comment: [Your comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216164/how-to-divide-floating-point-numbers-using-variables-with-integer-result#comment60065970_36216323) is caused by a "carriage return" character (the end of line in windows) in your text. Remove them from the variable `length` to make all work correctly. Maybe like this: `length=${length//[!-0-9]/}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
echo $(( length / 1024 )) | bc -l
```

You've already lost the part after decimal point before `bc -l` as `$(( length / 1024 ))` performs integer division.

You can use `bc -l` like this:

```
length="2402267538"
answer=$(bc -l <<<"scale=2; $length / 1024")
echo "$answer"

2345964.39
```

Little more verbose using `awk`:

```
answer=$(awk -v len=$length 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f\n", len/1024}')
echo "$answer"

2345964.39
```

Or this:

```
answer=$(awk -v len=$length 'BEGIN{printf "%d\n", len/1024}')
echo "$answer"

2345964
```

Comment: The first answer, throws an error like this

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M

and the second answer retains two decimal values after the calculation

Comment: If you don't want to restrict to 2 decimal points then use: `awk -v len=$length 'BEGIN{printf "%f\n", len/1024}'`

Comment: Apparently, this works fine
 
answer=$(awk -v len=$length 'BEGIN{printf "%.0f\n", len/1024}')

echo $answer

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `ksh` would simplify the task:

```
$ length=2402267538

$ answer=$((length/1024.00))
$ echo $answer
2345964.392578125
```

One way with awk:

```
$ answer=$(awk "BEGIN{printf(\"%f\n\",$length/1024);}")
$ echo $answer
2345964.392578
```

If you only need the integer part of the result (works with both `bash` and `ksh`):

```
$ answer=$((length/1024))
$ echo $answer
2345964
```

If your length variable is a floating point number, you can trim it that way:

```
$ length=2402267538.12
$ ilength=${length%%.*}
$ answer=$((ilength/1024))
$ echo $answer
2345964
```

Comment: using the above statement, how do I just retain value before the decimal point??

Comment: Do not use shell variable in awk like this, pass it to awk using `-v var="$var"`

Comment: @anubhava I usually don't. It's not forbidden though, one just need to be careful.